# Prometheus not scraping additional scrapes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator

I am deploying prometheus using stable/prometheus-operator chart. It is installed in `monitoring` namespace. In the `default` namespace I have a pod running named `my-pod` with three replicas. This pod spits out metrics on port 9009 (I have verified this by doing k port-forward and validating the metrics show up in localhost:9009). I would like prometheus-operator to scrape these metrics. So I added the configuration below to `values.yaml`

```
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    additionalScrapeConfigs:
    - job_name: 'my-pod-job'
      scrape_interval: 15s
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
      - role: pod
        namespaces:
          names:
          - default
      relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
        action: keep   
        regex: 'my-pod'
```

I then install prometheus using the command below:

```
helm upgrade --install prometheus stable/prometheus-operator \
--set kubeEtcd.enabled=false \
--set kubeControllerManager.enabled=false \
--set kubeScheduler.enabled=false \
--set prometheusOperator.createCustomResource=true \
--set grafana.smtp.existingSecret=smtp-secret \
--set kubelet.serviceMonitor.https=true \
--set kubelet.enabled=true \
-f values.yaml --namespace monitoring
```

However, when I go to `/service-discover` I see

```
my-pod-job (0/40 active targets)
```

**Question**

How can I configure prometheus such that it scrapes metrics from pods running in default namespace and spitting out metrics on port 9009?

Answer (score 7):

I'll try to give a **fully working answer** with explanation.

#### Short answer

When working with prometheus **operator** adding the following annotations is not enough:

```
prometheus.io/path: <path_to_scrape>
prometheus.io/port: "<port>"
prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
```

You also need to add the following section in the helm chart under `prometheusSpec.additionalScrapeConfigs` :

```
prometheusSpec:
  additionalScrapeConfigs:
    - job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'
      kubernetes_sd_configs:
        - role: pod
      relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
          action: keep
          regex: true
```

Notice the `source_labels` - we're telling Prometheus to scrap pods with the `prometheus.io/scrape` annotation.

#### But why the auto-discovery feature is different in the Prometheus Operator?

If you worked before with Prometheus directly, you probably wondering why it is not scraping the annotations directly.

According to the Prometheus upstream team the annotation approach is very limited compare to the `*Monitor` (`ServiceMonitor` and `PodMonitor`).
Read more in [here](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/issues/1547#issuecomment-401092041).

#### I've added the relevant additionalScrapeConfigs and it is not working

Notice that you can setup `additionalScrapeConfigs` as an [array](https://github.com/rapid7/csp-ops-helm/blob/development/3rd-party/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L2661) or as an [inline block](https://github.com/rapid7/csp-ops-helm/blob/development/3rd-party/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml#L2692). In both cases, indentation issues might happen, so go to the Prometheus CRD (under the `monitoring.coreos.com/v1` api) and view the status, you might see some errors there.

#### Where can I view the scrapped pods?

In the Prometheus UI - go to Service Discovery:

[image]

Where you will see all the jobs you've added in (*kubernetes-pods* and *kubernetes-service-endpoints* in my case):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To tell prometheus to scrape pods, add these annotations:

```
...
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
        prometheus.io/port: '9009'
```

Comment: This this for prometheus-operator? https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator

Comment: @Anthony prometheus-operator... [No](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator#prometheusioscrape) - "...The prometheus operator does not support annotation-based discovery of services". It would be [ServiceMonitor](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/user-guides/running-exporters.md#create-a-service-that-exposes-pods) for prometheus-operator.

Comment: that is what I am using and struggling to figure out using `additionalScrapeConfigs ` how can I configure it to point to a specific pod and specific port.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned by @gears, if you want to scrape metrics from a specific pod or service, then it is mandatory to apply the prometheus scrape annotations to it. For example:

```
...
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        prometheus.io/path: <path_to_scrape>
        prometheus.io/port: "80"
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
...
```

However, as already stated:

> The prometheus operator does not support annotation-based discovery of
> services, using the
> [serviceMonitor](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/user-guides/running-exporters.md#the-goal-of-servicemonitors)
> CRD in its place as it provides far more configuration options.

Now, if I understand you correctly, the `ServiceMonitor` object should be created in the same namespace as the application lives in. You need to make sure that the `serviceMonitorNamespaceSelector` selects that namespace and that the Prometheus server has the appropriate permissions to access Service/Endpoints/Pod objects in that namespace.